# Post Json data to web methods

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I have the following variable that post it normally to the following web method.

```
data: "{item:" + JSON.stringify(json) + ",step:" + JSON.stringify(john) + " }",
```

The web method:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public static string GetCart(string item, string step)
        {

            HttpContext.Current.Session["f"] = item;
            HttpContext.Current.Session["l"] = step;

            return item;


        }
```

When I try to add the following variable the 3rd variable(mytest) is not posted

```
data: "{item:" + JSON.stringify(json) + ",mytest:" + JSON.stringify(json) + ",step:" + JSON.stringify(john) + " }",
```

The web method

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public static string GetCart(string item, string step, string mytest)
        {

            HttpContext.Current.Session["f"] = item;
            HttpContext.Current.Session["l"] = step;
            HttpContext.Current.Session["mytest"] = mytest;
            return item;


        }
```

Edit

And the post statment

```
$.ajax({

                type: 'POST',

                url: "mypage.aspx/GetCart",

                data: "{item:" + JSON.stringify(json) + ",mytest:" + JSON.stringify(json) + ",step:" + JSON.stringify(john) + " }",

                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

                dataType: 'json'
```

Comment: And what's in `json`? Also, I'm really lost at why do you need to make your own JSON implementation, instead of stringifying the whole structure.

Comment: Have you tried using Fiddler or the like to see what the actual request looks like?

Comment: My problem is that with the 2 variables my  statement works. When I add the 3rd variable not.  What is your suggestion? Do I have any problem in the code syntax or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need double quotes:

```
...
data: "{\"item\":" + JSON.stringify(json) + ",\"mytest\":" + JSON.stringify(json) + ",\"step\":" + JSON.stringify(john) + " }"
...
```

Alternatively, you could stringify once:

```
...
data: JSON.stringify({item: json, mytest: json, step: john })
...
```

Comment: Still doesnt post it. When i convert to string Session["mytest"] i am taking blank, from the other hand the Session["f"] has normally a value when i convert it to string

Comment: Is this an MVC3 or 4 app?  Take a peek at model binding value provider to see if the values are parsed properly.

Comment: it is a framework 4 app. What you do you suggest? I am really stack

Comment: I realize with firebug that the post occurs, the web method doesn’t take the variable

Comment: @focus - Maybe a long shot, but can you try sending those params in the same order as declared in the server-side handler? And tell us what the results are - best to send 3 distinct values to rule out some kind of parameter mixup...

Comment: I just tried with the same order and with the same names. Firebug show that the post ocuured normally. The red bullet i have put in c# code behind suspends the processes and i check the values. The two values has been recieved. The mytest string variable is not null but is empty

Comment: Thank you, finally your solution help me a lot